# Relationship between $\mathcal{Spec}(R)$ and $\mathcal{Spec}(R_{\text{red}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. I am wondering if there is any well-known relationship between  $\mathcal{Spec}(R)$ and $\mathcal{Spec}(R_{\text{red}})$ that would allow one to conclude

$[\mathcal{Spec}(R), \mathbb Z]\cong [\mathcal{Spec}(R_{\text{red}}), \mathbb Z]$,

where $[X, Y]$ denotes the semiring of continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ under pointwise addition and multiplication.

I am asking because I am reading a theorem in some notes that seems to require such a group isomorphism.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by saying continuous maps in the context of schemes, but if you really are just looking at the underlying topology of $\mathrm{Spec}$, then this is unchanged under going to the reduced ring. (There is a bijection of prime ideals between $R$ and $R/N$, where $N$ is the nilradical of $R$).

Comment: @Joppy I am referring to the Zariski topology on the spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Spec(R)$ and $Spec(R_{red})$ are homeomorphic via the map induced by the projection $R \to R_{red}$.